# Angular-phonecat getting started (Bower install) fail

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, bower

my problem is described in the following image:

[image]

The main problem is that im getting a: Bower ENOENT     no bower.json present  error and as you can see in the image (second command) the file is actually present. So ive been trying to find what actually bower install does and havent found it in the NPM documentation and Git documentation as well

Also, in the research ive done some forums suggest installing bower globally and it hasnt worked

Since i've been googling for about 3 nights looking for somebody with the same problem and havent found anybody else with the problem I started wondering about if I changed any environment variable. So i uninstalled node.js and Git and then reinstalled both programs without any change in the result

Hope somebody can help me with this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Bower is a package manager for HTML http://bower.io/. 'bower install' will download all the packages listed in bower.json and add them to a folder called 'bower_components'

You must have bower install globally via

```
npm install -g bower
```

To get a list of NPM packages installed successfully global use:

```
npm list -g
```

Having a look at the github issues of that Repository(Angular-phonecat) theres alot of issues related to bower(https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/search?q=bower&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93), which is strange because bower is not that complicated. Have you looked through any of those fixes.

Comment: Yes, ive looked throught them

I even installed the GIT and Node JS in a VPN which I have access to and it installed without any problem. The computer that is having the issue has Windows 8.1 and the VPN which could run "npm install" succesfully has windows XP.

This thread looks like tries to solve the same problem, but in a different context which i dont understand. [link]https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep/issues/100

Comment: I've been even trying to find out in plain words what bower install actually does, so i can track all the files it uses, I mean, what i want to know is which files it looks for and I havent found a well detailed explanation (for people that don't understand that much the dependencues and related terms) to work with

Comment: I looked in differente places (including bower API) what does bower install (ommiting the package name) and didnt founf any result. 

To solve the problem I edited the package.json where it says:
"postinstall": "bower install",
to
"postinstall": "bower install bower.json",

Comment: What version of bower are you using? on this recent post https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1849 the user downgraded to 1.3.12 to stop the same issue, note: to install a specific local version on 'NPM install' change "bower": "^1.3.1" to "bower": "1.3.12" in package.json